# Count records per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I'm trying to count the number of appointments in each month for the year of 2014, where the date formatting is like '22-JAN-14' 
I've tried variations of these two codes so far and both come up with "YEAR": invalid identifier.

CODE 1

```
SELECT count(*), MONTH(dateofappointment) as month, YEAR(dateofappointment) as year
FROM appointment
GROUP BY month
HAVING YEAR(dateofappointment) ='14'
ORDER BY month;
```

and CODE 2

```
select count(*)
from appointment
group by month(dateofappointment)
having year(dateofappointment) = '14';
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? MS SQL Sever? Is `dateofappointment` is a `DateTime` column or `varchar`?

Comment: @Selva TS, i'm using oracle, and all the document i'm provided with says it's type 'date'.

Comment: @Shandep Updated my answer to use oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Extract`Reference

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment) "Month", count(*)
FROM appointment
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateofappointment) = '2014'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment);
```

To have a month name rather than number

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment), 'MM'), 'MONTH') "Month", count(*)
FROM appointment
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateofappointment) = '2014'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment);
```

Comment: Updated my answer to use oracle as you specified

Comment: Thank you, this finally worked. I just had to change the 14 to a 2014, as Zohar suggested.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the display of the months from numbers to the month name?

Answer (score 2):

Data by month and year, sorted by date from oldest to newest:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM dateofappointment) "Year",
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment) "Month",
    count(*) 
FROM
    appointment 
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(year FROM dateofappointment),
    EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment) 
ORDER BY
    1,
    2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your year should be an integer.
Also, unless your appointments took place in the first century, your year should be 2014.

try this:

```
select  EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment), count(*)
from appointment
where EXTRACT(year FROM dateofappointment) = 2014
group by EXTRACT(month FROM dateofappointment)
```